# Resize Image from Client-side for multiple HTML input

Tags: javascript, php, html

I find this helpful [article](https://www.askingbox.com/tutorial/html5-upload-images-with-client-side-resize) for resizing images before uploading them to the server. I want to use it for some repetitive HTML input but I'm having a problem altering the javascript code since I'm not really good in javascript.

This is what I've tried so far. But as can see, I didn't get the value for that `imagefiles`

```js
function fileChange(e) { 

    for (var i = 1; i <= e.target.files.length; i++) { 
      document.getElementsByClassName('inp_img[i]').value = '';
      var file = e.target.files[i-1];
      alert(file);
      if (file.type == "image/jpeg" || file.type == "image/png") {

        var reader = new FileReader();  
        reader.onload = function(readerEvent) {

          var image = new Image();
          image.onload = function(imageEvent) { 

            var max_size = 800;
            var w = image.width;
            var h = image.height;

            if (w > h) {  if (w > max_size) { h*=max_size/w; w=max_size; }
          } else     {  if (h > max_size) { w*=max_size/h; h=max_size; } }

          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          canvas.width = w;
          canvas.height = h;
          canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);
          if (file.type == "image/jpeg") {
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
          } else {
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");    
          }
          document.getElementsByClassName('inp_img[i]').value += dataURL + '|';
        }
        image.src = readerEvent.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName('inp_files[i]').value = ''; 
      alert('Please only select images in JPG- or PNG-format.');   
      return false;
    }
  }

}

var imagefiles = document.getElementsByClassName('inp_files');
console.log(imagefiles);
for (var i=0; i<imagefiles.length; i++)
{
  alert(imagefiles[i].value);
  imagefiles[i].addEventListener('change',fileChange, false);
}
```

```html
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { ?>
      <div class="w3-quarter">
        <div class="w3-card w3-container" style="min-height:150px">
          <header class="w3-container w3-blue w3-row-padding w3-center w3-margin-top">
           <label><b>Instruction <?php echo $counter; ?></b></label>
         </header><br>
         <b><?php echo $row['cf_941']; ?></b><br>
         <?php echo $row['productname']." (".number_format($row['cf_949'])."%) - ".$row['cf_953']." ".$row['cf_955']; ?><br>
         <?php echo "Area: ".$row['cf_951']." sm ";?>
         <hr>
         <label><b>Remarks</b></label><br>
          <?php echo $row['cf_945']; ?><br>
         <hr>
         <b>Attached Photo</b><br>
         <input class="inp_files[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" type="file">
         <!--<?php echo $row['instructionsid']?> -->
         <input class="inp_img[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" name="img[<?php echo $row['instructionsid']?>]" type="hidden" value="">
         <p><strong>Note:</strong> Only .jpg, .jpeg,png formats allowed <br><hr>
          <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="itemStatus[<?php echo $row['instructionsid']?>]" 
          <?php if ($row['cf_947']=='1') {
            echo "checked";
          } ?> >
          <label> Work completed</label><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php
      $counter++;
    }

    ?>
```

How can I alter this code to be able to resize the images from multiple input file and then send to PHP side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are mixing the `name` and `class` attributes when you create your HTML code. Instead of:

```
<input class="inp_files[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" type="file">
```

it should read ...

```
<input class="inp_files" name="inp_files[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" type="file">
```

If you want to receive the proper *instructionsid* when you post the files back to the server, I would recommend to create a loop similar to this one:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    ...
  <input class="inp_files" id="<?php echo $row['instructionsid']?>" name="inp_files[<?php echo $row['instructionsid']?>]" type="file">
  <input class="inp_img" name="inp_img[<?php echo $row['instructionsid']?>]" type="hidden" value="">
  <input class="w3-check" name="itemStatus[<?php echo $row['instructionsid']?>]" type="checkbox" <?php print ($row['cf_947']=='1') ? 'checked' : ''?>>
    ... 
<?php
}
?>
```

Your JS code will also need some rewrites as it contains several errors (i.e. `document.getElementsByClassName('inp_img[i]').value = '';` searches for an element like `<input class="inp_img[i]">`, the `i` needs to be escaped properly).

```
function fileChange(e) { 

    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) { 
      let self= this;
      self.field= e.target.id;
      let file = e.target.files[i];
      console.log(self.field, file);
      if (file.type == "image/jpeg" || file.type == "image/png") {

        let reader = new FileReader();  
        reader.onload = function(readerEvent) {

          let image = new Image();
          image.onload = function(imageEvent) { 

            let max_size = 800;
            let w = image.width;
            let h = image.height;

            if (w > h) {  if (w > max_size) { h*=max_size/w; w=max_size; }
          } else     {  if (h > max_size) { w*=max_size/h; h=max_size; } }

          let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          canvas.width = w;
          canvas.height = h;
          canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);
          let dataURL = '';
          if (file.type == "image/jpeg") {
            dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
          } else {
            dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");    
          }
          document.getElementsByName('inp_img[' + self.field + ']')[0].value += dataURL + '|';
        }
        image.src = readerEvent.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      alert('Please only select images in JPG- or PNG-format.');   
      return false;
    }
  }
}

var imagefiles = document.getElementsByClassName('inp_files');
console.log(imagefiles);
for (var i=0; i<imagefiles.length; i++)
{
  imagefiles[i].addEventListener('change',fileChange, false);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. this works like a charm. i'm not really familiar with javascript, thus the confusion to get the element.

Comment: @HNA great to hear it worked! If you want to learn more about Javascript (it's surely worth the time) I would recommend to read some tutorials in the [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). Thanks for accepting my answer :-)